# Why might SelectedIndex be 0 after calling ClearSelected and attaching a DataSource?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm working with a `ListBox` that uses a `List<SomeObject>` as its `DataSource`.

When an item needs to be removed from the ListBox, I am removing the item from the list and then re-adding the list as a DataSource.

This works fine except for the item at the end of the list (including lists with one item). In these cases I get an error when I try to re-attach the DataSource:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.

This makes sense to me - the ListBox has is trying to Select an item at an index which is now out of bounds. What doesn't make sense is that this behaviour persists even when I call `ClearSelected()` on the ListBox immediately prior to re-attaching:

```
if (this.RulesBox.DataSource != null) this.RulesBox.DataSource = null;
this.RulesBox.ClearSelected();
this.RulesBox.DataSource = this.Rules;
```

What do I need to do to properly clear the SelectedIndex?

Comment: A downvote and a close flag - anyone care to elaborate?

Comment: Wasn't me, but this is probably because it is not immediately obvious that this is winforms, and you do not have a proper tag. For the question itself, how do you re-attach the data source?

Comment: Hi @Andrei - thanks for the feedback. Have updated the question, which now answers your question too hopefully.

Comment: @MethodMan I'm not setting it in my code - it will only have a value based on the user selected an item. The problem is therefore that when the last item (Index == Count-1) is removed, the SelectedIndex is now out of range.

Comment: Seems to be a debugger configuration problem, check this [almost identical thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274357/invalidargument-value-of-0-is-not-valid-for-selectedindex)

Comment: @TomWright that was not obvious prior to your edit.. sorry I will delete my comment since what `Steve` has provided will do the trick

Comment: My experience is that you have to bind the `ListBox` to a `BindingSource`, and then you can bind and unbind the `BindingSource` to your 'List' without the `ListBox` firing off at the data change and trying to set its index to 0 before the data is there for the `ListBox` to use.  I see from @Steve's answer his experience is similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use a BindingSource to remove the items from your List.
This will avoid to reattach the List to the ListBox.

In this example I use a `List<string>`

```
ListBox l = new ListBox();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

void Main()
{
    Form f = new Form();
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Click += onclick;
    b.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;

    List<string> ls = new List<string>()
    {"Steve", "Mark", "John"};
    bs.DataSource = ls;
    l.DataSource = bs;
    l.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    f.Controls.Add(b);
    f.Controls.Add(l);
    f.Show();    
}

void onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(l.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        bs.RemoveAt(l.SelectedIndex);    
    }
}
```

By the way, I was able to reproduce your problem with ClearSelected. It seems that you need to call ClearSelected two times to effectively remove the selection from any item in the listbox.
Something like this

```
 this.RulesBox.ClearSelected();
 this.RulesBox.ClearSelected();
```

but, again, I think you should work with a BindingSource instead of detaching and reattaching the DataSource. With few items, probably it is not a big deal but, if you have many items, I think you should notice performances degradation with this attach/detach approach.

Comment: Thanks Steve - I'll give BindingSource a try. Was hoping to be able to simply repeat `ClearSelected()`, but unfortunately this didn't work in my case.

Answer (score -1):

This might help:
Set the Listbox property `Listbox.FormattingEnabled = true` Or Set `.SelectedValue`

From the Listbox Control FormattingEnabled page:

Setting the `FormattingEnabled` property to true causes the Format event to be raised for each visible member of the  `ListControl`, `SelectedIndex`, `SelectedValue` and `FormattingEnabled` are related as follows:

> If `FormattingEnabled` is `false`, `SelectedIndex` will not be set to -1
>   when `SelectedValue` is blank.
>
> If `FormattingEnabled` is true, `SelectedIndex` will be set to -1 when
>   `SelectedValue` is blank.

Comment: You could probably format this answer so it's easier to read.